# Create and connect to a socket returns Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have an running server written in C, and I need to create a ruby client for this server. The server is running on ubuntu through virtual machine, and I am working on Mac OS ( i dunno if this really matters) .

What i have in the client till now is

```
myStreamSock = Socket::new( Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0 )
myaddr = [Socket::AF_INET, 3333, 127, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0].pack("snCCCCNN")

myStreamSock.connect( myaddr )
```

This returns

```
`connect': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Is this because the server is running on vm, or am i missing something here?

Any help is really apreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `Socket` instead of `TCPSocket`? Is that port open and accepting connections? Have you tried something like `telnet localhost 3333`?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Ruby to port scan to do this I use a very simple socket connection:

```
begin
  a_sock = Socket.new(:INET,:STREAM)
  raw = Socket.sockaddr_in(port,@ip)
  port_status(port,"Open") if a_sock.connect(raw)
rescue (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) #check if the port is closed
  port_status(port,"Closed")
rescue (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
  port_status(port,"Timed Out")
ensure
  a_sock.close if a_sock
end

def port_status(port,status)
  @ports.merge!("port_#{port}".to_sym => {status: status})
end
```

Obviously this is not the same as what you are trying to do but it should give you some idea. Also some variables are not visibly declared because this is taken out of a block.

This also might be useful for you to look through https://thebc.ch/blog/217/ruby-of-wisdom/